# Why is ".hasClass()" not working as I expect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if a certain html element has a certain class.

In the example below, I am asking if an element has the class "fa". As you can see, the `<i>` element has the class `fa`, but I' getting `false` when utilizing the `.hasClass()` function.

```
>> $("#row-CleceBasingstoke button:first").html()
"<i style="padding:3px;" class="fa fa-lg more-less-icon fa-plus-square-o"></i>"

>> $("#row-CleceBasingstoke button:first").hasClass("fa")
false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: Please put your html code also

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: Because the `button` hasn't this class... `i` isn't a button...

Comment: Sorry I missformated my post, and some parts of the code could not be seen. Now I have edited it.

That code is what I type in the Mozila console.

Comment: If you want to check if the button contains element with specific class, you can use: `!!$("#row-CleceBasingstoke button:first:has(.fa)").length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fa` class is on the child element. So you need to use `hasClass` on the child.

```js
console.log( $("button i").hasClass("fa") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><i class="fa"></i></button>
```

Or you search for an element with the class inside:

```js
console.log( $("button").find(".fa").length >= 1 );
// or
console.log( $("button>.fa").length >= 1 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><i class="fa"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#row-CleceBasingstoke i:first").hasClass("fa")
```

Comment: It should be `#row-CleceBasingstoke button:first i`

Comment: But he didn't say there was a button containing the "i" in his example HTML

Comment: His example is the contents of `$("#row-CleceBasingstoke button:first")` which is a button.

Comment: Oh, it does really. My bad.